How to refresh jquery datatable without database call
In my ASP.NET Core MVC app, I am using a jQuery datatable and it uses Ajax calls to load data from database. The datasource is a List<Student> object.
Now I load the datatable with List<Student> object. And I remove or add any student object to List<Student> in the client side, how I can reflect these changes in the datatable?
After removing 1 or 2 items from the List<Student>, how we can reflect these changes in the datatable without reloading the page again?
I tried with this code:
$('#example').DataTable().ajax.reload(); // nothing happens to datatable

exampletable.ajax.reload(); // nothing happens to datatable


What do you mean, "without database call"? How could that make sense, if you want to repeat the AJAX request? If that doesn't make a "database call", then how is it supposed to get the current set of records?

"The datasource is a List object." - which is a server-side construct, right? So then how do you remove anything from that list, "in the client side"? Are you already making a request in the background, to modify the data on the server side? Or did you so far only remove an item from the DOM on the client side? This really needs more details. Please go read [ask] and [mre], and edit your question accordingly.

Only do client operation to remove/add the item in DataTable is acceptable.  But you load the data by ajax call database, so what's you purpose for render the DataTable without database call? Did you also do not want do database add/remove operation?

Hi Rena - Finally there will be a button to save the changes back to database. But before that I want to add\remove items from the datatable. These changes will be saved later on save button click.  Now I want to update or refresh the datatable without reloading the datatable from database. how to do that ???

See https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().delete()

And I remove or add any student object to List in the client side - how you do this is the real question.   Javascript doesn't have a List<T> so this isn't "client-side".  if you're making an ajax call, then simply add/edit/remove the datatable's row at the same time (eg row().delete()).  Be sure to edit the datatable's .data() and not manipulate the HTML/DOM directly.

A whole working demo to achieve your requirement for doing database call after client side add/remove operation:
Model
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Grade { get; set; }
}
public class StudentChangesModel
{
    public List<Student> AddedStudents { get; set; }
    public List<Student> DeletedStudents { get; set; }
}  

View
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Student Management";
}

<h1>Student Management</h1>

<!-- Table to display students -->
<table id="studentsTable" class="display" style="width: 100%;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Grade</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

<!-- Form to add a new student -->
<h2>Add New Student</h2>
<div>
    <label>Name: </label><input type="text" id="nameInput" />
    <label>Age: </label><input type="text" id="ageInput" />
    <label>Grade: </label><input type="text" id="gradeInput" />
    <button id="addStudentBtn">Add Student</button>
</div>

<!-- Button to save changes -->
<button id="saveChangesBtn">Save Changes</button>

@section Scripts {
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var addedStudents = [];
            var deletedStudents = [];

            $(document).ready(function () {
                var table = $('#studentsTable').DataTable({
                    ajax: {
                        url: '/Students/GetStudents',
                        dataSrc: ''
                    },
                    columns: [
                        { data: 'id' },
                        { data: 'name' },
                        { data: 'age' },
                        { data: 'grade' },
                        { data: null, defaultContent: '<button class="delete-btn">Delete</button>' }
                    ]
                });

                // Add new student to the table
                $('#addStudentBtn').click(function () {
                    var newStudent = {
                        id: 0, // Empty for new student
                        name: $('#nameInput').val(),
                        age: parseInt($('#ageInput').val()),
                        grade: $('#gradeInput').val()
                    };

                    // Add the new student to the DataTable
                    table.row.add(newStudent).draw();

                    // Track the new student in "addedStudents" array
                    addedStudents.push(newStudent);

                    // Clear input fields
                    $('#nameInput').val('');
                    $('#ageInput').val('');
                    $('#gradeInput').val('');
                });

                // Capture delete button click
                $('#studentsTable tbody').on('click', 'button.delete-btn', function () {
                    var row = table.row($(this).parents('tr'));
                    var data = row.data();

                    // Track removed students only if they exist in DB (have an ID)
                    if (data.id) {
                        deletedStudents.push(data);
                    }

                    // Remove the row from DataTable
                    row.remove().draw();
                });

                // Save changes to the server
                $('#saveChangesBtn').click(function () {
                    console.log(addedStudents)
                        console.log(deletedStudents)
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/Students/SaveStudents',
                        type: 'POST',
                        contentType: 'application/json',
                        data: JSON.stringify({
                            addedStudents: addedStudents,
                            deletedStudents: deletedStudents
                        }),
                        success: function (response) {
                            addedStudents = [];
                            deletedStudents = [];
                            alert('Changes saved successfully!');
                            table.ajax.reload();
                        },
                        error: function (error) {
                            console.error('Error saving changes', error);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
}

Controller
public class StudentsController : Controller
{
    private readonly MvcProjContext _context;

    public StudentsController(MvcProjContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    public IActionResult GetStudents()
    {
        List<Student> students = _context.Student.ToList();
        return Json(students);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SaveStudents([FromBody] StudentChangesModel changes)
    {
        // Process added students
        foreach (var student in changes.AddedStudents)
        {
            _context.Add(student);
        }

        // Process deleted students
        foreach (var student in changes.DeletedStudents)
        {
            var data = await _context.Student.FindAsync(student.Id);

            _context.Student.Remove(data);
        }
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Ok(new { message = "Changes saved successfully!" });
    }
}


If you're adding/deleting items in the list from the client side, you should be able to also remove them from the list without the need for a reload. That would be ok from a transactional point of view, until you are sure to make those changes in the underlying data service.
Anyway, you must, somehow, apply those changes in the database before reloading the table from the ajax call. This will also show any external changes to the data on your page.
You can do it, for example, with another ajax call which doesn't have to update the table immediately.
